# Parallel computation of a quadratic form in RcppParallel

Tags: c++, r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I want to write a code to compute v^T Av using RcppParallel. Here v is a vector of size n and A is a n by n matrix. My idea is to evaluate Av in a parallel fashion and then compute the inner product of this vector with v. Here is my code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;

struct Par_MatVec_Mult: public Worker {

  const RMatrix<double> Mat;
  const vector<double> Vec;
  vector<double> output;

  Par_MatVec_Mult(RMatrix<double> A, vector<double> v, vector<double> Av): \ 
  vector<double> Av): Mat(A), Vec(v), output(Av) { }
  void operator() ( size_t begin, size_t end) {

    for( size_t i = begin; i < end; i++ ) {
      RMatrix<double>::Row rowi = Mat.row(i);
       output.at(i) = inner_product( rowi.begin(), rowi.end(),Vec.begin(), \
       0.0 );
    }
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double Parallel_MatVec_Mult( NumericMatrix A, vector<double> v ){

  vector<double> b( A.nrow(), 0.0 );
  Par_MatVec_Mult Av(A, v, b);
  parallelFor(0, A.nrow(), Av);
  return inner_product( Av.output.begin(), Av.output.end(), v.begin(), 0.0   );
}
```

While compiling I get the following error.

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Rcpp::NumericMatrix {akaRcpp::Matrix<14>}' 
to 'RcppParallel::RMatrix<double>'
```

It is pretty clear to me that NumericMatrix and RMatrix are two different objects. However I don't know what is exactly their difference and how can I change my code to get rid of this error.

BTW, I use RStudio 0.99.903 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

The [single-argument constructor](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppParallel/blob/57d5a6f5acdef27696ee8ec75600203f67922825/inst/include/RcppParallel/RMatrix.h#L194-L200) for `RMatrix` is marked `explicit`:

```
inline explicit RMatrix(const Source& source) 
   : data_(const_cast<Source&>(source).begin()),
     nrow_(source.nrow()),
     ncol_(source.ncol())
{}
```

You have given the `Par_MatVec_Mult` constructor this signature

```
Par_MatVec_Mult(RMatrix<double> A, vector<double> v, vector<double> Av)
```

and are attempting to pass it a `NumericMatrix` later on. This would require an implicit conversion in the construction of the `RMatrix`, but since what would otherwise be a suitable constructor was marked `explicit`, this is not allowed, and you get an error.

Here is a simplified example demonstrating this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Wrapper {
private:
    std::size_t nr;
    std::size_t nc;

public:
    template <typename T>
    explicit Wrapper(const T& t)
        : nr(t.nrow()),
          nc(t.ncol())
    {}

    std::size_t size() const { return nr * nc; }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(Rcpp::NumericMatrix x) {
    // Wrapper w = x;   // Error: conversion from ‘Rcpp::NumericMatrix
                        // {aka Rcpp::Matrix<14>}’ to non-scalar
                        // type ‘Wrapper’ requested

    Wrapper w(x);       // Ok

    return w.size();
}
```

---

In your case the fix is easy: just change the signature of `Par_MatVec_Mult`'s constructor to this:

```
Par_MatVec_Mult(NumericMatrix A, vector<double> v, vector<double> Av)
```